# When $F'(x) = f(x)$ where $f$ is not continuous...

Tags: real-analysis

This question comes from problem 2vii of Chapter 14 of Spivak's Calculus.

Problem 2vii) Let $f$ be the function shown in the link below. Let $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt$. For what values of $x$ does $F'(x) = f(x)$?

[image: Picture of <span class=]$f$" />

I know $F'(x) = f(x)$ for every $x$ except $0$, because $f$ is continuous everywhere except $0$, but I don't know if $F'(0) = f(0)$ is true, false, or undecidable.

Going back to limit definitions, I need to evaluate $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+}(\frac{F(h)}{h})$. How to do this?

Comment: Hint: calculate $\frac{F(h)}h$ exactly for values of $h$ of the form $h=\frac1{2^k}$ and $h=\frac3{2^{k+1}}$.

Comment: I think $F$ won't be differentiable at $0$. Anyway, how is $f(0)$ defined? (Based on the picture, it's not defined.)

Comment: Based on the new picuture, $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @GregMartin $\frac{F(h)}{h} = \frac{1}{2}$ for $h = \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$ or $h = \frac{3}{2^{k+1}}$, for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Try proving that the limit does not exist.

Hint1:

> You will be done if you find two sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ both approaching 0 such that $\lim F(x_n)/x_n \neq \lim F(y_n)/y_n$.

Hint 2:

> Pick $x_n$ So that $\lim F(x_n)/x_n$ is as large as possible and $\lim F(y_n)/y_n$ is as small as possible.

Hint 3:

> Using geometry: $\lim_{n\to \infty} F(1/2^n) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2^{n+2}} + ... = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ and $F(1.5/2^n) = F(1/2^n) + 0.25/2^n = 1.5/2^{n+1}$.

Comment: Ok but they are equal? Both limits converge to 1/2. In fact, all the terms $F(x_n)/x_n$ and $F(y_n)/y_n$ are always 1/2 for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: Now I'm convinced $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+} (\frac{F(h)}{h}) = 1/2$

Comment: Well in any case, this does prove the limit must be 1/2 if it exists, and since $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^-} (\frac{F(h)}{h}) = 0 \neq 1/2$, then $F'(0) \notin \mathbb{R}$, which solves my problem.